# Wait Times in a Yule Process

Tags: probability

We have a pure birth process and want to know the transition distribution by looking at the wait times. My prof writes,

$$
P(W_k < t < W_{k+1})= Pr(W_k \leq t) - Pr(W_{k+1} \leq t)
$$

where $W_k$ is the wait time to $k^\text{th}$ event.

I'm not understanding how the equality is true. I tried to break up the event
$\{W_k < t < W_{k+1}\}$ into $\{(W_k < t)\text{ and }(W_{k+1} > t)\}$ and playing around with the probability of a union, but still not making much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the event $\{W_{k+1}\leq t\}$ is contained in the event $\{W_k < t\}$ since if $W_{k+1} \leq t$ then certainly $W_k < t$. So, now notice that $$\{W_{k}<t\} \cap \{W_{k+1}>t\} = \{W_k < t\} \cap \big(\{W_{k+1} \leq t\}^c\big) = \{W_k < t\}\backslash \{W_{k+1}\leq t\}$$ Now, for any events $E$ and $F$, if $F \subset E$ then $P(E\backslash F) = P(E)-P(F)$. Can you go from here?

Comment: Imagine t = 6.  The intersection is between all Wk < 6 (so the set could contain values for Wk like 1,2,3,4,5.9) and all Wk+1 greater than 6 (so that set could contain values like 6.1, 7, 8, 9,...).  The two sets are disjoint.  Would the probability not then be 0?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. But, imagine that $t=6$, then $W_k < 6 < W_{k+1}$ is saying that the $k$th event occurred before time $6$ and the $(k+1)$st event occurred after time $6$. This is the same as considering all possible outcomes with the $k$th event occurring before time $6$ and removing those outcomes for which the $(k+1)$st waiting time also occurs at or before time $6$. That is, $$ \{W_k < 6 < W_{k+1}\} = \{W_k < 6\} \backslash \{W_{k+1} \leq 6\} $$

Comment: @DanSchwartz The two sets you mentioned in your first comment are not disjoint. If you look at $W_k$ as the time the $k$th costumer entered a store, then certainly you can imagine situations where the $k$th costumer enters before time $6$ and the $(k+1)$st customer enters after time $6$. IE. there are some outcomes where $W_k < 6 < W_{k+1}$, so this is a non-empty event.